# Can HatchShading be applied to a general Graphics3D object?

Tags: graphics3d, color

Is it possible to apply HatchShading (a new Mathematica 12 option for Plot3D and friends) to a generic Graphics3D object (for example, spheres, tubes, and arrows), such as:

```
a = {0, 0, 0};
b = {1, 0, 0};
c = {0, 1, 0};
Graphics3D[{
   Arrowheads[0.2]
  , Arrow[ Tube[{a, b}, 0.05]]
  , Arrow[ Tube[{a, c}, 0.05]]
  , Sphere[a, 0.2]
  }]
```

[image: some 3d graphics objects]

If not, how can I render such a Graphics3D object in grayscale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the directives `HatchShading[]` and `Lighting -> "Neutral"` (*"white light sources in default positions"*) or `Lighting -> "Accent"` (*"a directional white light in default direction"*) before the graphics primitives:

```
Graphics3D[{Lighting -> "Neutral"
    , HatchShading[]
    , Arrowheads[0.2]
    , Arrow[ Tube[{a, b}, 0.05]]
    , Arrow[ Tube[{a, c}, 0.05]]
    , Sphere[a, 0.2]
    }, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

With `Lighting -> "Accent"` we get

[image: ![enter image description here]